# Consulta usando Sequelize resultando em erro "column "id" does not exist"

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize-js

Estou testando a API REST que estou desenvolvendo. Estou utilizando Sequelize e PostgreSQL. Na API existe a tabela `users` com os seguintes campos:

- `user_id`
- `user_nickname`
- `user_fullname`
- `user_password`
- `created_at`
- `updated_at`

Ao tentar inserir ou retornar usuários é apontado o seguinte erro no console NodeJS:

> Executing (default): SELECT "id", "user_nickname", "user_fullname", >"user_password", "created_at" AS "createdAt", "updated_at" AS "updatedAt" FROM >"users" AS "User";
> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SequelizeDatabaseError: column "id" does not >exist

A migration feita através do Sequelize foi a seguinte:

```
module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.createTable('users', {
      user_id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false
      },
      user_nickname: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
      },
      user_fullname:{
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
      },
      user_password: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
      },
      created_at: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        allowNull: false
      },
      updated_at: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        allowNull: false
      }
    });
  },

  down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.dropTable('users');
  }
};
```

E a classe herdada de `Model` é a seguinte:

```
const { Model, DataTypes } = require('sequelize')

class User extends Model {
  static init(connection) {
    super.init({
      user_nickname: DataTypes.STRING,
      user_fullname: DataTypes.STRING,
      user_password: DataTypes.STRING
    }, {
      sequelize: connection
    })
  }
}

module.exports = User
```

A consulta está sendo feita assim:

```
async findAll(req, res) {
  const users = await User.findAll()

  return res.json(users)
}
```

Eu fiz a inserção de alguns usuários pelo próprio banco de dados para tentar fazer um SELECT através do Sequelize na API, mas resulta no mesmo erro.

Comment: A consulta aparentemente está errada. Você fez `SELECT "id", ...` enquanto deveria usar `SELECT "user_id"...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O campo `id` é a chave primária padrão utilizada pelo Sequelize quando nenhuma é informada no modelo, o que é o seu caso (vide método `init` do `User`).

- [*Migrations*](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/migrations.html) servem para criar a estrutura do seu banco de dados;
- [*Models*](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-basics.html) servem como um modelo para realizar consultas, inserções e etc. com o Sequelize. É com base no modelo que o Sequelize sabe como é a sua tabela.

Ou seja, o Sequelize não sabe a estrutura do seu banco de dados, sabe apenas daquilo especificado no `Model`.

Seu `User` deveria ser algo como:

```
class User extends Model {
  static init(connection) {
    super.init({
      user_id: { primaryKey: true, type: DataTypes.INTEGER }, // Indicando a chave primária
      user_nickname: DataTypes.STRING,
      user_fullname: DataTypes.STRING,
      user_password: DataTypes.STRING
    }, {
      sequelize: connection
    })
  }
}
```